# custom post type wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: wordpress

How can i customize wp_dropdown_catagories to show custom posts. Let say posts created by woocommerce. Here is my code which shows blog posts. But I want custom posts in dropdown. How can I achieve that?

```
<?php $args = array(
        'show_option_all'    => 'All Catagories',
        'show_option_none'   => '',
        'orderby'            => 'ID',
        'order'              => 'ASC',
        'show_count'         => 1,
        'hide_empty'         => 0,
        'child_of'           => 0,
        'exclude'            => '1,5',
        'echo'               => 1,
        'selected'           => 0,
        'hierarchical'       => 0,
        'name'               => 'cat',
        'id'                 => '',
        'class'              => 'postform',
        'depth'              => 1,
        'tab_index'          => 0,
        'taxonomy'           => 'category',
        'hide_if_empty'      => false,
             ); ?>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: This dropdown is used for displaying categories,not for post. What you want to do exactly?

Comment: I am using a search-box where users can search for a string. User can also select a category and results will be shown for only selected category. This is working fine for blog. But I don't know how to customize drop-down to show custom post types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this. Added taxonomy of woocommerce in above code. Just replace value for taxonomy in product_cat.

```
'taxonomy'           => 'product_cat',
```